# issue with css grid container when grid height bigger then page(device) height

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a issue with css grid , i build a container with two div in it with css grid and i want to adjust container to page center. I use this code :

```css
html{
    width: 100vw;
    height : 100vh;
}
body{
    height : 100%;
}

.container-fluid{
    width:100%;
    height : 100%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 200px auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.logo-container{
    background-color: khaki;
}

.form-container{
    height :540px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/media-query.css">
    <title>Login & Register User With Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="logo-container">
               <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-container">
          <h1>Form</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.css">
</body>
</html>
```

as you see when grid container height bigger then page height a issue occurs (please see code result).
when use height for body tag ,  grid height overflowing and when delete height from body tag every thing is ok but in this situ container can't adjust container in center of page.
what is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
}

.container-fluid {
  min-height: 100vh; /* at least screen height */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* to consider the border inside the height */
}

.logo-container {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.form-container {
  height: 540px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <h1>Form</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh; /* full height */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  /* first row at 200px max-height and second row at 540px max-height */
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto,200px) minmax(auto,540px); 
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.logo-container {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.form-container {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <h1>Form</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```